# inequality $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2}\,dx <3 $

Tags: calculus

Let $f\colon [0,1]\to[0,1]$ be $C^2$ function, $f(0)=f(1)=0$,  and $f''(x)< 0,\forall x\in[0,1]$,  then

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2}\,dx <3 $$

I try this: If $\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2} <3, \forall x\in[0,1] $, then we get the desired result. But this is not correct.

By rolle theorem, there exists a $\epsilon \in(0,1)$ such that $f^\prime(\epsilon)=0$, so

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2}\,dx =\int_0^\epsilon\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2}\,dx+ \int_\epsilon^1\sqrt{1+{f^\prime(x)}^2}\,dx$$

then, What should I do next? How to use the condition 'concave function'? Thanks! special attention should be pay to  $f\colon [0,1]\to[0,1]$

Answer (score 6):

The integral is the length of the graph of $f$ on $[0,1]$. Can you show the curve is concave and inside the square of side $1$ with one side on $[0,1]$?

If so, the graph should be shorter than the sum of three top sides of the square.

Remember to use Rolle to get that the first derivative vanishes somewhere between $[0,1]$.

And to use that $0>\int_{x}^{y}f''(t)dt=f'(y)-f'(x)$, with $x<y$ to show $f'$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: the curve inside the square, then the graph is shorter than the sum of three top sides of the square. Why? Thanks!

Comment: Not only from being inside. If it wiggles it can be arbitrary long. But if it is concave (down) not.